# openfire connect clients other than spark

Tags: openfire, psi, qxmpp

I have openfire installed on my windows 7 and I am able to add users in the web admin interface .I am also able to connect clients using spark (locally on localhost).When I try to connect with other clients the connection fails .I have tried Psi (http://psi-im.org/) and the gui example for QXmpp (https://github.com/qxmpp-project/qxmpp/tree/master/examples/GuiClient) .Psi fails saying it is problem with certificates：  **There was an error communicating with the server.Details: Authentication error: Not authorized.** I looked into the security settings and can't find anything that lets the QXmpp gui client connect successfuly .

What can I do to minimize security concerns so my QXmpp clients can connect successfully?I might enable those later as I get more comfortable with xmpp programming. I would appreciate any piece of help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if openfire disables other clients to connect by default ,but by installing the    Client Control   plugin(http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/clientControl.jar) and allowing all clients to connect I was able to connect my QXmpp clients.Hope this helps somebody some day.